# Upload file using Guzzle 6 to API endpoint

Tags: php, api, laravel, guzzle, guzzle6

I am able to upload a file to an API endpoint using Postman.

I am trying to translate that into uploading a file from a form, uploading it using Laravel and posting to the endpoint using Guzzle 6.

Screenshot of how it looks in Postman (I purposely left out the POST URL)
[image]

Below is the text it generates when you click the "Generate Code" link in POSTMAN:

```
POST /api/file-submissions HTTP/1.1
Host: strippedhostname.com
Authorization: Basic 340r9iu34ontoeioir
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 6e0c3123-c07c-ce54-8ba1-0a1a402b53f1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileContents"; filename=""
Content-Type: 


----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileInfo"

{ "name": "_aaaa.txt", "clientNumber": "102425", "type": "Writeoff" }
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Below is controller function for saving the file and other info. The file uploads correctly, I am able to get the file info.

I think the problem I am having is setting the multipart and headers array with the correct data.

```
public function fileUploadPost(Request $request)
{
    $data_posted = $request->input();
    $endpoint = "/file-submissions";
    $response = array();
    $file = $request->file('filename');
    $name = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = base_path() .'/public_html/documents/';

    $resource = fopen($file,"r") or die("File upload Problems");

    $file->move($path, $name);

    // { "name": "test_upload.txt", "clientNumber": "102425", "type": "Writeoff" }
    $fileinfo = array(
        'name'          =>  $name,
        'clientNumber'  =>  "102425",
        'type'          =>  'Writeoff',
    );

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $res = $client->request('POST', $this->base_api . $endpoint, [
        'auth' => [env('API_USERNAME'), env('API_PASSWORD')],
        'multipart' => [
            [
                'name'  =>  $name,
                'FileContents'  => fopen($path . $name, 'r'),
                'contents'      => fopen($path . $name, 'r'),
                'FileInfo'      => json_encode($fileinfo),
                'headers'       =>  [
                    'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
                    'Content-Disposition'   => 'form-data; name="FileContents"; filename="'. $name .'"',
                ],
                // 'contents' => $resource,
            ]
        ],
    ]);

    if($res->getStatusCode() != 200) exit("Something happened, could not retrieve data");

    $response = json_decode($res->getBody());

    var_dump($response);
    exit();
}
```

The error I am receiving, screenshot of how it displays using Laravel's debugging view:

[image]

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The way you are POSTing data is wrong, hence received data is malformed.

[Guzzle docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#multipart):

> The value of `multipart` is an array of associative arrays, each
>   containing the following key value pairs:
>
> `name`: (string, required) the form field name
>
> `contents`:(StreamInterface/resource/string, required) The data to use in the
>   form element.
>
> `headers`: (array) Optional associative array of custom headers to use with the form element.
>
> `filename`: (string) Optional
>   string to send as the filename in the part.

Using keys out of above list and setting unnecessary headers without separating each field into one array will result in making a bad request.

```
$res = $client->request('POST', $this->base_api . $endpoint, [
    'auth'      => [ env('API_USERNAME'), env('API_PASSWORD') ],
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'FileContents',
            'contents' => file_get_contents($path . $name),
            'filename' => $name
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'FileInfo',
            'contents' => json_encode($fileinfo)
        ]
    ],
]);
```

Comment: the above solution works when i don't add filename' => $name as argument. When i add filename nothing get send over.

Comment: Should you send the file_get_contents or an fopen?

Comment: @zardilior As I looked at `stream_for` function defined in `guzzlehttp/psr7` package both are handled properly.

Comment: @AdityaJoshi in my case I had it as a binary string and it worked only by sending it with filename and receving it in laravel with request->has

Answer (score 3):

```
$body = fopen('/path/to/file', 'r');
$r = $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', ['body' => $body]);
```

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=file

Comment: Please don't post code only answers. Add some text to accompany your code.

Comment: What you posted is what worked for me. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=file#sending-form-files

Comment: This is not a correct answer since the OP asked for multipart upload but it is still useful.

Comment: @Pawel how would I post a file which is online somewhere? file is at `https://example.com/file.mp4` how would I send this via the `$client->request(...` without downloading the file first? is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel 8 with guzzle I am using this:

The idea is that you are reading the file with fread or file_get_content, then you can use the Laravel getPathname() which points to the file in /tmp

```
        $response = $this
            ->apiClient
            ->setUserKey($userToken)
            ->post(
                '/some/url/to/api',
                [
                    'multipart' => [
                        'name'     => 'avatar',
                        'contents' => file_get_contents($request->file('avatar')->getPathname()),
                        'filename' => 'avata.' . $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension()
                    ]
                ]
            );
```