# Post Multipart and Json together with Guzzle in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phonegap-build, guzzle

I'm trying to POST multipart and json data with [**Guzzle**](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html) to build my apps with [**Phonegap Build API**](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/developer-api/write/). I've tried many adjustment but still got error results. Here's the latest function I'm using:

```
public function testBuild(Request $request)
{
     $zip_path = storage_path('zip/testing.zip');
     $upload = $this->client->request('POST', 'apps',
          ['json' =>
            ['data' => array(
              'title'         => $request->title,
              'create_method' => 'file',
              'share'         => 'true',
              'private'       => 'false',
            )],
           'multipart' => 
            ['name'           => 'file',
             'contents'       => fopen($zip_path, 'r')
            ]
          ]);
      $result = $upload->getBody();
      return $result;
}
```

This is my the correct curl format that has success result from the API, but with file I have in my desktop:

```
curl -F file=@/Users/dedenbangkit/Desktop/testing.zip 
-u email@email.com 
-F 'data={"title":"API V1 App","version":"0.1.0","create_method":"file"}'
 https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps
```

Comment: `This option cannot be used with body, form_params, or json` from http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#multipart

Comment: Then what your suggestion? should I revert this post to normal CURL post?

Comment: you can do 2 requests or you code it into the url

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133244/upload-file-using-guzzle-6-to-api-endpoint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned before, you cannot use `multipart` and `json` together.

In your `curl` example it's just a multipart form, so use the same in Guzzle:

```
$this->client->request('POST', 'apps', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name' => 'file',
            'contents' => fopen($zip_path, 'r'),
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'data',
            'contents' => json_encode(
                [
                    'title' => $request->title,
                    'create_method' => 'file',
                    'share' => 'true',
                    'private' => 'false',
                ]
            ),
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works for me. But why array didn't work for the contents data?

Comment: Because `contents` is (simply) a byte array. `json` in Guzzle is just a small fancy helper that does `json_encode()` for you, but it works only for "simple" bodies, multipart option doesn't have such helper.

Comment: Got it, now I understand how guzzle works. Thanks a ton!