# Send uploaded file via cURL PHP to an API

Tags: php, api, file, curl

I am trying to send an uploaded file via cURL with PHP.

```
   <?php
if (!isset($_POST['idcampagnestatus'])) {
    header("Location: exampleblablavacatures/?vacature=0&errors=1");
    die();
}

$file_path = 'cv/' . time() . '-' . $_FILES['docsbestand']['name'];

file_put_contents($file_path, file_get_contents($_FILES['docsbestand']['tmp_name']));

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "exampleapiurl",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"docsbestand\"; filename=\"" . 'exampleblablawp-content/plugins/hoezorgjij-api/' . $file_path . "\"\r\nContent-Type: "  . $_FILES['docsbestand']['type'] . "\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

unlink($file_path);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    if (json_decode($response)->FOUT) {
        header("Location: exampleblablavacatures/?vacature=0&errors=1");
        die();
    } else {
        header("Location: exampleblablavacatures/?vacature=0&errors=0");
        die();
    }
}
```

I tried other things, but often I get an empty file. The idea is that I save a file to the webserver and then send it to an API which should process it and put it on their own webserver. More details are sent through the API and these all work perfectly. What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you're missing the use of a higher-level library which will save you the pointless effort of doing things like typing out MIME attachment boundaries by hand.

Comment: might help to search the web... 
https://binfalse.de/2016/06/21/forget-the-at-use-curl-file-create/

Comment: @LarsStegelitz unfortunately that does not seem to work

Comment: @miken32 I avoided this at first, because this will make my program quite big for this task. However, I think I am going to take your advice. Thanks.

Comment: No, it will make *your* program much smaller!

Comment: [Guzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133244/upload-file-using-guzzle-6-to-api-endpoint) to the rescue!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Comment: @Utkanos Thank you, I will look into this one too