# Posting Form data with Guzzle always returns 404

Tags: laravel, curl, http-status-code-404, guzzle

I have be having a hard time sending a simple multipart form request using Guzzle.
For some reason I always get a 404 response but I am make the same request using cURL I get 200 ok and the data is posted.

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is even after solving a similar issue.

Here's my cURL code:

```
$body = shell_exec('curl -H \'Content-Type: multipart/form-data\' -H \'Accept: application/json\' \
-F "photo=@ "'.$photo.'" \
-F "api_key="'.$apiKey.'" \
-F "id=14784" \
"'.$apiUrl.'" 2>&1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

The shell works fine from the command line but I need to convert it to make the request from a controller so I've added the form fields to Guzzle but not I get a 404.

Here's the Guzzle code:

```
 $guzzle = $client->request('POST', config('services.url'), [
                'multipart' => [
                    ['headers' => [
                            'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
                            'Accept: application/json'
                        ],
                        'name'     => 'api_key',
                        'contents' => config('services.key'),
                    ],
                    [
                        'name'     => 'photo',
                        'contents' => $photo
                    ],
                    [
                        'name'     => 'id',
                        'contents' => "4084",
                    ],
                ]
            ]);
```

I've changed the url for the sake of posting but I'm struggling to find the cause so if anyone knows please give me a heads up!

** EDIT **
I've been able to get past the 404 but not I get a 500 Error, not sure if it is the form or the recipient server because I can make a POST request to the same endpoint successfully with Postman.

Still baffled.

Comment: `'name' => 'photo=@',` ???

Comment: Yes I need to add that as a param, see the orignal cURL request

Comment: Also `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` in the curl code, and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the Guzzle code?

Comment: You should understand what the working code is doing before you try replicating it. Like what the significance of the `@` is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload file using Guzzle 6 to API endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133244/upload-file-using-guzzle-6-to-api-endpoint)

Comment: I'll have a look at the post, the '@' is part of the instruction for making a request with cURL that's as much as I know.

Answer (score 2):

there're 2 mistakes
1st you set base_uri and then you called it again

2nd mistakes

as you mentioned you're gonna using multipart

you should use `multipart` not `form_params`
and you don't need json options on request part

header changed to this `Content-Type' => multipart/form-data`

therefore request should be look like this

```
$response = $client->post('/', [
    'multipart' => $params,
]);
```

reference can be seen here for [multipart](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart)

Answer (score 1):

When you set you base_uri you dont have to add it on the post. Most likely you will call and url similar to this `http://httpbin.com/http://httpbin.com`,.

```
$response = $client->post('/', ['json' => [
    'form_params' => [
        ....
    ],
]]);
```