# How to upload file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I want to upload file to another server with API in a Laravel project.
I already use postman and that API works!
In Laravel project I can upload file to my server but I want to upload that file to another server with API.

```
$api_key = $_COOKIE['api_key_supplier'];
            $pic = $request->file('file');
            try {
                $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
                $response = $client->post($this->sub_url . "up", [
                    'headers' => [
                        'Authorization' => "$api_key"
                    ],
                    'form_params' => [
                        "filedata" => $pic,
                        "type" => 4,
                    ]
                ]);
            $res = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
            if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200)
                return response()->json(['success' => 1, 'msg' => 'success']);
        } catch (ClientException $e) {
            return $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
        }
```

Comment: please share your code of controller.

Comment: $api_key = $_COOKIE['api_key_supplier'];$pic = $request->file('file');

Comment: try {
                $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
                $response = $client->post($this->sub_url . "up", [
                    'headers' => [
                        'Authorization' => "$api_key"
                    ],
                    'form_params' => [
                        "filedata" => $pic,
                        "type" => 4,
                    ]
                ]);

Comment: $res = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
                if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200)
                    return response()->json(['success' => 1, 'msg' => 'success']);
            } catch (ClientException $e) {
                return $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
            }

Comment: Thank for your Answers I found the best help for me!
[This is the best way for upload file in Laravel with API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133244/upload-file-using-guzzle-6-to-api-endpoint)