how to pass file inputs from controller to an API controller in Laravel 10?
I'm working on a Laravel 10 project for a module called 'culinary', and I'm using RESTful API. so I have a main controller and API controller, where the main controller will make a request to the API controller using guzzlehttp.
in the Edit page, I have a file input. when the form is submitted, I want to update the data in the table using the new data from the form.
my code are as follow:
Main Controller -> CulinaryController.php
    public function update(Request $request, Culinary $culinary)
    {
        // dd($request->all(), $culinary->id);
        $client = new Client();
        $token = Session('token');

        try {
            $multipart = [];

            foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
                // Check if the input is a file
                if ($request->hasFile($key)) {
                    // If it's a file, add it to the multipart array with the appropriate format
                    $multipart[] = [
                        'name' => $key,
                        'contents' => fopen($value->path(), 'r'),
                        'filename' => $value->getClientOriginalName(),
                    ];
                } else {
                    // If it's not a file, add it as a regular field to the multipart array
                    $multipart[] = [
                        'name' => $key,
                        'contents' => $value,
                    ];
                }
            }
            // dd($multipart);

            $url = 'http://localhost/api/culinary/'.$culinary->id;
            $response = $client->put($url, [
                'multipart' => $multipart,
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                ]
            ]);
            // dd($response);

            $json = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
            dd($json);

            return redirect()->route('admin.culinary.index')->with('success', 'Culinary created successfully');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['errors' => $e->getMessage()])->withInput();
        }
    }

API Controller -> Api/CulinaryController.php
    public function update(Request $request, Culinary $culinary)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'test',
            'request' => $request->all(),
            'cover_photo' => [
                'name' => $request->file('cover_photo')->getClientOriginalName(),
                'path' => $request->file('cover_photo')->path(),
                // other file properties as needed
            ],
            'old' => $culinary,
        ]);
    }

routes/api.php
    Route::apiResource('culinary', CulinaryController::class);

when I open the dd($multipart) code, it shows that the 'cover_photo' field has a value because I already picked a file using the file input. but why am I getting this error message when the dd($multipart) is commented?

Server error: POST http://localhost/api/culinary/3 resulted in a 500 Internal Server Error response: { "message": "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null", "exception": "Error", "file": "D:\ (truncated...)


what is the route of this function public function update(Request $request, Culinary $culinary)  ?

if you getting error in this line try
'filename' =>  $value ?? $value->getClientOriginalName()

@Hamelraj I added the routes code. where did the $value come from?

you are using >getClientOriginalName() many places. so not sure which line you get this error. not sure which function for this route 'http://localhost/api/culinary/'.$culinary->id;
anyway check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133244/upload-file-using-guzzle-6-to-api-endpoint

I think the error happens in the API controller in the $request->file('cover_photo')->getClientOriginalName() part because when I uncomment the dd($multipart) I don't get the error. so that means the $value->getClientOriginalName() isn't causing the error.

@Hamelraj I have edited the api route

you get null value for this $request->file('cover_photo') so for contents you have to use similar  'contents' => file_get_contents($path . $name),

Why would you guzzle/http request to your api if its in the same app? Cant you just create a custom request then call the method of your api controller?

@Mr.Kenneth the short answer is my manager wants it that way XD . the longer answer is I think there may be a case in the future where the API is going to be used by other modules so it would make more sense to put the code in an API endpoint.. or are we (my team) misunderstanding things?

Got it. Anyways you are doing a POST REQUEST to http://localhost/api/culinary/'.$culinary->id where its method Api/CulinaryController@update is trying to get getClientOriginalName from file cover_photo Instead you are passing an array called multipart so you should loop request['multiart'] then get its value.

TLDR, Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null error is because you are trying to get the value of getClientOriginalName from a non existing file of cover_photo

You sent 'Accept' => 'application/json' You can not mix it with "multipart"
So if you want to send file via json you may want to do something like
$client->post($url, [
                'json' => [
                        'name' => $key,
                        'contents' => fopen($value->path(), 'r'),
                        'filename' => $value->getClientOriginalName(),
                ],
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
                    'Content-type' => 'application/json',
                ]
            ]);

But in this way you will not have object in $request->file
So just use 'Content-type' => 'multipart/form-data' instead of 'Content-type' => 'application/json'

this doesn't work. I'm getting "json_encode error: Type is not supported" error instead.
